# CSS Display terminal without scrollbars and responsive

Tags: html, css, terminal, textarea, pre

please, I have a problem with terminal simulator. I want show one line in full length without wrapping of course but text (`text-align: left` of course). It's fine in desktop but if you will smaller the window you will see horizontal scrollbar. I solve this with `max-width: 100vw` but then scrollbar is still visible below the text. It's for desktop. I think that this is solved. But have you some better ideas for terminal emulator? What library is standard used which can copy your code, etc...? Thank for advice

My html scratch

```html
<div class="terminal">
<pre class="terminal">cd ~
mkdir Projects
git clone https://github.com/zrebec/JavaLearning/ThisIsVeryVeryVeryLongURLPathToDestination/DesignPatterns.git
/zeroscratch.sh init</pre>
</div>
```

and css scratch

```css
.terminal {
    // Layout
    padding: 5pt;
    border-radius: .5em;
    display: inline-block;

    // Colors
    background-color: $secondary;
    color: $color5;

    // Text
    font-family: monospace;
    font-weight: $font-weight-bold;
    line-height: $terminal-line-height;
    text-align: center;
}

.terminal pre {
    // Layout
    overflow-x: auto;
    margin: -17px; // This is for compatibility with mobile devices

    // Text
    text-align: left;
}
```

Don't worry about variables, I'm using [Sass](https://sass-lang.com/) for normal programming. But I have some questions please:

1. It's needed to have negative margin? I read that it's for mobile browser compatibility. And yes, otherwise page is *scroll-able* which is really ugly. But the question is, existing most modern solutions for terminal emulator?
2. It's better use `<pre>` or `<textarea>` for terminal simulator? Thank you

Full my code is [on my codepen](https://codepen.io/littleTheRabbit/pen/MWaJGrp)

Thanks for any advice

PS: **My desire is avoid Javascript or Bootstrap for now**. Thank you for understand

Best Regards

Comment: Do you want the text to be scrollable horizontally (as you currently have it with `overflow-x: auto;`) or should the text wrap, breaking any word at the end of a line?

Comment: Of sure always scrollable horizontally. Because some people just triple code to catch the line and paste in (then wrap is OK) but some people just select one line and it will be doesn't work then of course

Comment: If you want an editable terminal-like interface, take a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47459914/trying-and-failing-to-make-a-linux-terminal/64217041#64217041.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood well, please check if this is the behavior you're wanting to happen :

```css
.terminal {
  width: 90%;
  height: 100px;
  padding: 10px;
  background: #000;
  color: #0f0;
  border-radius: 10px;
  font-family: monospace;
  text-align: left;
}

.terminal pre {
  margin: 10px;
  padding: 10px;
  overflow-x: scroll;
  overflow-y: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div class="terminal">
  <pre>cd ~
mkdir Projects
git clone https://github.com/zrebec/JavaLearning/ThisIsVeryVeryVeryLongURLPathToDestination/DesignPatterns.git
/zeroscratch.sh init</pre>
</div>
```

You had both items with the same class which was conflicting with the browser applying the styling. And if you want the scrollbar to appear only horizontally, just make sure also to hide the vertical bar with `overflow-y: hidden;`.

Here's a fiddle, so you can resize the window and see it working responsively. Hope it helped!

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/v1qxrdoL/)